# Frequency of rows by ID

Tags: r

The data set contains three variables: id, sex, and grade (factor).

```
mydata <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4), sex=c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1),
                     grade=c("a","b","c","d","e", "x","y","y","x", "q","q","q","q", "a", "a", "a", NA, "b"))
```

For each ID, I need to see how many unique grades we have and then create a new column (call N) to record the grade frequency. For instance, for ID=1, we have five unique values for "grade", so N = 4; for ID=2, we have two unique values for "grade", so N = 2; for ID=4, we have two unique values for "grade" (ignore NA), so N = 2.

The final data set is

```
mydata <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4), sex=c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1),
                     grade=c("a","b","c","d","e", "x","y","y","x", "q","q","q","q", "a", "a", "a", NA, "b"))
mydata$N <- c(5,5,5,5,5,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
```

Comment: This would seem like a job for a `for` loop, doing an iteration for each unique value ID and possibly a nested `for` loop for each unique grade.

Comment: For loops are not the answer in R. Unless they are (which is not the case here).

Comment: I was also wondering if it would be possible to make use of the  *dplyr* and provide counts for unique groups.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the package `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)

#I have removed NA's, up to you how to count them
mydata[,N_u:=length(unique(grade[!is.na(grade)])),by=id]
```

Very short, readable and fast. It can also be done in base-R:

```
#lapply(split(grade,id),...: splits data into subsets by id
#unlist: creates one vector out of multiple vectors
#rep: makes sure each ID is repeated enough times

mydata$N <- unlist(lapply(split(mydata$grade,mydata$id),function(x){
  rep(length(unique(x[!is.na(x)])),length(x))
}
))
```

Because there was discussion on what is faster, let's do some benchmarking.

Given dataset:

```
> test1
Unit: milliseconds
          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
 length_unique 3.043186 3.161732 3.422327 3.286436 3.477854 10.627030   100   b
       uniqueN 2.481761 2.615190 2.763192 2.738354 2.872809  3.985393   100  a
```

Larger dataset: (10000 observations, 1000 id's)

```
> test2
Unit: milliseconds
          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
 length_unique 11.84123 24.47122 37.09234 30.34923 47.55632  97.63648   100  a 
       uniqueN 25.83680 50.70009 73.78757 62.33655 97.33934 210.97743   100   b
```

Answer (score 11):

**New answer:**

The `uniqueN`-function of [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) has a `na.rm` argument, which we can use as follows:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)[, n := uniqueN(grade, na.rm = TRUE), by = id]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > mydata
>     id sex grade n
>  1:  1   1     a 5
>  2:  1   1     b 5
>  3:  1   1     c 5
>  4:  1   1     d 5
>  5:  1   1     e 5
>  6:  2   0     x 2
>  7:  2   0     y 2
>  8:  2   0     y 2
>  9:  2   0     x 2
> 10:  3   0     q 1
> 11:  3   0     q 1
> 12:  3   0     q 1
> 13:  3   0     q 1
> 14:  4   1     a 2
> 15:  4   1     a 2
> 16:  4   1     a 2
> 17:  4   1    NA 2
> 18:  4   1     b 2
> ```

---

**Old answer:**

With *data.table* you could do this as follows:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)[, n := uniqueN(grade[!is.na(grade)]), by = id]
```

or:

```
setDT(mydata)[, n := uniqueN(na.omit(grade)), by = id]
```

Comment: @RichardScriven that gives me a different result

Comment: I get the same result as shown in your answer when using `na.omit(grade)`. What is it that you get?

Comment: @docendodiscimus Now I get the same result. Probably made a mistake yesterday evening. Added the option to the answer.

Comment: ha, `uniqueN` could use a `na.rm` argument.. - [#1455](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1455)

Answer (score 7):

A dplyr option that makes use of `dplyr::n_distinct` and its `na.rm`-argument:

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(N = n_distinct(grade, na.rm = TRUE))
#Source: local data frame [18 x 4]
#Groups: id [4]
#
#      id   sex  grade     N
#   (dbl) (dbl) (fctr) (int)
#1      1     1      a     5
#2      1     1      b     5
#3      1     1      c     5
#4      1     1      d     5
#5      1     1      e     5
#6      2     0      x     2
#7      2     0      y     2
#8      2     0      y     2
#9      2     0      x     2
#10     3     0      q     1
#11     3     0      q     1
#12     3     0      q     1
#13     3     0      q     1
#14     4     1      a     2
#15     4     1      a     2
#16     4     1      a     2
#17     4     1     NA     2
#18     4     1      b     2
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks like we have several votes for `data.table`, but you could also use the base R function `ave()`:

```
mydata$N <- ave(as.character(mydata$grade),mydata$id,
                FUN = function(x) length(unique(x[!is.na(x)])))
```

Comment: Another idea, with base, is `rowSums(table(mydata[c("id", "grade")]) > 0)[mydata$id]`

Answer (score 4):

use tapply and lookup table

```
mydata <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4), 
                     sex=c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1),
                     grade=c("a","b","c","d","e", "x","y","y","x", "q",
                             "q","q","q", "a", "a", "a", NA, "b"))
uniqN <- tapply(mydata$grade, mydata$id, function(x) sum(!is.na(unique(x))))
mydata$N <- uniqN[mydata$id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dplyr method. I kept the summary table separate for tidy reasons.

```
library(dplyr)

summary =
  mydata %>%
  distinct(id, grade) %>%
  filter(grade %>% is.na %>% `!`) %>%
  count(id)

mydata %>%
  left_join(summary)
```